# AVAudioSession.sharedInstance() fails on several Macs

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I use AVFoundation framework for the audio recording. It works okay on my Mac (MBP 15" 2018) but prints an error (without crashing) on my teammate's Macs (MBP 15" 2017): **HALC_ShellDriverPlugIn::Open: Can't get a pointer to the Open routine**

It prints right after execution of the following line:
`let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()`

Then it doesn't record anything. Any thoughts how to solve this?

P.S. It's a Catalyst app, so it should work both on iOS and Mac

Comment: Have you got microphone permissions? Just a thought.

Comment: yes, I added it to plist file and it was allowed after app started